# Change UILabel textColor when UITableViewCell is highlighted?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a custom `UITableViewCell`, with an `UILabel` and an `UIImageView`. I want to change the background color and the text color when the cell is highlighted. In my `CustomCell`'s `setHighlighted` method, I have the following piece of code:

```
-(void)setHighlighted:(BOOL)highlighted {
    [super setHighlighted:highlighted];
    if(self) {
        if(highlighted) {
            self.title.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        } else {
            self.title.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        }
        //highlight background
        UIView *bgColorView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.frame];
        bgColorView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        [self setSelectedBackgroundView:bgColorView];
    }
}
```

I already tried to put the code for `textColor` change in the `tableView`'s `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`, but it's not the effect that I want - I want the text color to change when the user touches down on the cell - not at touch up.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should use the attribute `highlightedTextColor`. Set the color for the cell inside `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath` and it should look like this:

```
cell.textLabel.highlightedTextColor = [UIColor blueColor];
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
[cell.textLabel setHighlightedTextColor:[UIColor yellowColor]]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have custom label then use following code

```
lblPrd.highlightedTextColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
```

Answer (score 0):

override method

```
(void)setHighlighted:(BOOL)highlighted animated:(BOOL)animated {
    [super setHighlighted:highlighted animated:animated];
    //TODO set view highlighted color 
}
```

in custom tableviewcell

Answer (score 0):

In case you have a Storyboard or XIB, you can simply set this at `Attributes Inspector > Label > Highlighted`.